# Create MongoDB user who can only manage the documents he created

Tags: mongodb

I'm wondering id there is a way to create a new user for a database who can only manage his the documents he has created.
I've read almost everything regarding roles and custom roles in the MongoDB documentation but couldn't find what I'm looking for.

What I need is to create a user who can only create documents (not collections), reads others' documents, edit delete his own documents, and not to be able to edit nor delete documents were created by other users.

Is this possible?

If not, is there a workaround I can implement?

Answer (score 2):

At the point of creating the document, you can pass the user's id as one of the attributes so when you want to update or delete that document, you perform a check if the user that is trying to update that document is the person that initially created it.

Something has attributes moviename, dataAdded, userid

```
userId=12;
const data = Something.findOne({someDocument});
if(userId==data.userid){
   //perform update/delete
}else{
   //return error
}
```

Comment: Thank you, Hanis. I am doing something similar to this approach right now. It would be more efficient if there is I can create a custom role from within MongoDB that can be overridden by more privileged users.

Comment: Ok check this link out on creating custom roles. it might help. https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/how-to-create-dynamic-custom-roles-with-mongodb-stitch

Comment: Thank you again, Hanis. The article is talking about Mongo Stitch. I hope this can be applied to MongoDB community edition. I'll give it a try and see.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing built-in but you can use custom roles like this:

```
db.getSiblingDB("admin").createRole({
   role: "myDefaultRole",
   privileges: [
      {
         resource: { db: "myDB", collection: "myCollection" },
         actions: ["update", "insert", "remove", "find"]
      }
   ]
})

db.getSiblingDB("admin").createRole({
   role: "mySuperRole",
   privileges: [ {<maybe some additional privileges>} ],
   roles: [{ role: "myDefaultRole", db: "admin" }, {<maybe some additional roles>}]
})

db.getSiblingDB("admin").createUser({
   user: "user1",
   pwd: passwordPrompt(),
   roles: [{ role: "mySuperRole", db: "admin" }]
})

db.getSiblingDB("admin").createUser({
   user: "user2",
   pwd: passwordPrompt(),
   roles: [{ role: "myDefaultRole", db: "admin" }]
})

function hasRole(v_user, v_role) {
   return v_user != null && db.getSiblingDB(v_user.db).getUser(v_user.user, { filter: { roles: v_role } }) != null;
}
```

And then use it like this:

```
const currentUser = db.runCommand({ connectionStatus: 1 }).authInfo.authenticatedUsers.shift();

use myDB
db.myCollection.insertOne({ user: currentUser });

var data = db.myCollection.findOne({ someDocument });
if (data.user == currentUser || hasRole(currentUser, { role: "mySuperRole", db: "admin" })) {
   //perform update/delete
} else {
   //return error
}
```

Note, users and roles can be defined in several databases. Thus you should check both, the database and user names. I prefer to create them commonly in the `admin` database.

Instead of custom roles you may also use field [customData](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.createUser/), but I think custom roles are more flexible.

Comment: Thank you very much, Wernfried! This looks promising. Will give it a try and let you know.

Comment: @rajashekar, this applies only for MongoDB Atlas, i.e. when you use MongoDB Cloud service. When you run MongoDB on your premises then you don't have it.