# How to add document-level permissions in mongodb from mongoshell

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, mongo-shell

I am in a requirement to add document-level permissions in MongoDB. The only owner of the document should be able to update it. For this, I found a [link](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/define-roles-and-permissions/) but couldn't able to add those permissions from the mongo-shell.

Is there any way to add these roles other than using Realm tool as suggested [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm/mongodb/define-roles-and-permissions/)

Sample collection is as follows:

```
_id: 60b508a9a5d06230eb6e961d,
name:"aldjfl",
ownerId:"a98dc1b1-5ad5-4147-95e7-97bee2a014d"
position:"senior"
```

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67629291/create-mongodb-user-who-can-only-manage-the-documents-he-created/67632399#67632399